# Can you explain how this line of code work (worksheet function)

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm new to vba and I have a project which at first seems quite simple but when I started to look at the range references I was totally lost. The Goal is to make a sum of multiple columns with one or two criterias.

```
For j = 9 To 12
    For i = 3 To 6

  datecol = 3

  Cells(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(R3C" & datecol & ":R" & Lastrow2 & "c" & datecol & ", R3C2:R" & 
  Lastrow2 & "C2, R" & i & "C8"

    Next i
  datecol = datecol + 1

Next j
End sub
```

What I have understand is that Cells(i,j) is where the output of my formula will be write.
`.FormulaR1C1` return the formula as a string in the cell (i,j) -I think this is why we have `="=sumifs()`-

Then we have `SUMIFS(R3C" & datecol & ":R" & Lastrow2 & "c" & datecol & ")` but what `":R"`, `"c"`, `& "` mean ?

I know that this argument is the range use by the formula to make the sum but I don't understand the way  ranges are referenced, and I have the same question for `R3C2:R" "C2, R"`.

Help would be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There is two way to references cells in Excel. A1 reference style uses Letters for columns and Numbers for rows, while R1C1 reference style uses number both for columns and rows (R meaning Row and C column). Manipulating offsets is easier with number, so R1C1 reference style is often used when those operations are required. You will find tons of informations by looking for "Excel R1C1" on internet.

Comment: @VincentG Thank you very much, I have write down the references and for the first loop I have R3C2:R16C2 for the first argument of my function, it was the mix of concatenation and variable that got me confused. It's much more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Review and Suggestions

**What do** `:R`, `c`, `&`  **mean ?**

In the context of **R1C1** style `R` means row and `C` column. The `&` is a **concatenation operator** used to join the values ​​of two variables or constants. Very common used to create String variables.

For the macro you are trying to code you don't need to complicate yourself with `.FormulaR1C1` use `.Formula` instead.

The line `datecol = datecol + 1` is useless because `datecol = 3` is inside the loop, so `datecol` will go back to 3 everytime the macro is looping. To solve this, `datecol = 3` should be outside the loop.

When working with VBA is better to use functions that are meant to be runned in VBA and not in Excel, unless you wish to insert Excel formulas in cells. For instance the `SUMIF` function in VBA is:

`application.worksheetfunction.sumif(range,criteria,sum_range)`

Example of use:

`SumIfResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A10"), "In", Range("B1:B10"))`

**Descriptive Variables**: use name or letters for your variables that describe them. It is easy to write software that works satisfactory. But it is very hard to write reliable, understandable and maintainable code. One important aspect is using good variable and function names. For instance, in the code below I changed the variables `i` and `j` for `col` and `row_number`.

I don't really get what you are trying to do, but I modified a little bit your code so you can maybe take some useful ideas.

```
Sub sum_columns()

'descriptive variable examples
Dim col As Long
Dim row_number As Long
Dim date_col As Long 
Dim last_row2 As Long

date_col = 3

For col = 9 To 12
    For row_number = 3 To 6 

'this looks very complicated try to code it as simple as possible
 'Cells(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(R3C" & datecol & ":R" & Lastrow2 & "c" & datecol & ", R3C2:R" & Lastrow2 & "C2, R" & i & "C8"

'example
Cells(row_number, col).Formula = "=SUMIF(D" & row & ":D" & row + 3,">100)"

'another idea
Cells(row_number, col) = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A10"), "In", Range("B1:B10")) 

    Next row_number
    date_col = date_col + 1

Next col
End Sub
```

### Note

The code above is ONLY meant for explanation purposes (concepts, examples and ideas) NOT for executing it.

Comment: Thanks you, I will try it. The goal is to make the sum of multiple columns (cost or revenue) with criterias ( Date, name).

Comment: in that case I think is better to use `application.worksheetfunction.sumif(range,criteria,sum_range)` or a loop that goes through the rows and sums if conditions are met. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693001/vba-loop-through-rows-sum-up-certain-rows-if-condition-is-met

Comment: `The R and C are columns`: In the context, R and C are not columns. In R1C1 style R means Row and C means Column.

Comment: @VincentG thanks for the clarification. I will edit my answer accordingly.